What is addressing mode [IndexReg * ScaleFactor + Offset] used for?
In X86 assembly, what type of operations use the addressing mode with this format?
IndexReg * ScaleFactor + Offset

mov rax, [r15 * 8 + 56]


Imagine you have an array of structs...

Usually with the disp32 being the absolute address of an array, like mov eax, [arr + rdi*4], not a small integer constant like your 56.
This was always possible in 16 and 32-bit mode, but in 64-bit mode only possible for non-PIE code models where static data is in the bottom or top 2GiB of virtual address-space.  (See 32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux? / Mach-O 64-bit format does not support 32-bit absolute addresses. NASM Accessing Array)
Other use-cases include LEA to shift-and-add like lea eax, [rdi*8 + 56].

In theory you could use it to iterate through an aligned array where the scaled register holds address/8, perhaps in a loop also using that value as a byte offset into an array of smaller elements like [rbx + rdi].
Note that it's only encodeable with a 4-byte disp32 not a 1-byte disp8 (https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#SIB), so the machine-code format doesn't encourage uses like your [r15*8 + 56].  x86 addressing modes always have a base register and/or a disp32 which could (before 64-bit mode) hold an absolute address of the start of an array.
See Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes) for example use-cases for every x86 addressing mode. (Although it doesn't try to be exhaustive to cover every way to use each addressing mode.)

I read the entire linked x86 addressing modes post.  I didn't see an entry specically for this address format. It was still a useful read, though.
My usecase is 64bit, only. So, in 64bit, this is basically not used anymore?
From this post, my understand is this format is used to read data from the beginning/ending 2gb of the address space -- so, because of PIE, it's no longer applicable? Well, I guess besides the usecase for LEA you mentioned.

@Dess  My mov eax, [arr + rdi*4] example used a 64-bit register (RDI) to show that it is still useful on x86-64 (in a non-PIE executable).  You can see GCC use it that way if you compile with -fno-pie, like int arr[1024]; int foo(size_t idx){ return arr[idx] }.  The addressing mode in the machine code is [disp32 + idx*scale] whether disp32 is an address or a small integer.  The first Q&A I linked was Agner Fog asking about that use case which worked fine before -pie became the default GCC config for typical Linux distros; his question mentions the static array use-case.

@Dess :Should I have used mov rax, [arr + rdi*8] or something, like did you miss that it was still 64-bit code since I changed the instruction to simplify the machine code (no REX prefix)?

@Dess: But yes, in modern x86-64 code, usually we do build PIE executable and kernels which makes this addressing-mode unusable for static arrays.

You cleared up the remaining confusion I had, thank you. Towards the end, I wasn't sure in which situations it was still useful, but now I get it. If the program's address is not randomized, it can still be used in 64bit. It's used to create addresses with a displacement from the beginning. Randomized addresses messes up the calculations.
